# $scope not updated from async error callback

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update the `$scope` from an promise error callback as follows:

```
 var reportErrors = function (error) {
      $scope.state['save-mappings']='update';
      ...
 }

 myService.myMethod().then(postProcess).catch(reportErrors);
```

However, the `$scope` is not updated properly and the corresponding ng-if does not update...

```
<div ng-if="state['save-mappings'] === 'update'">
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**: postProcess function:

```
var postProcess = function (data) {
    var associateMediasPromise = function () {
        return SupplierImportService.associateMedias($scope.getLink($scope.ngDialogData.import.links, 'associate-medias'));
    };
    var matchArticlesPromise = function () {
        return SupplierImportService.matchArticles($scope.getLink($scope.ngDialogData.import.links, 'match-articles'));
    };
    var updatePostProcessPromise = function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('init-headers');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('update-import', data.data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('change-articles-page');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('update-statistics');
        $scope.setPopinState('save-mappings', 'done');
    };
    return associateMediasPromise()
        .then(matchArticlesPromise)
        .then(updatePostProcessPromise);
};
```

from myMethod:

```
var myMethod = function () {
 return $http.post(...);
};
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1pg0dw0g/2/

Comment: could you set a debugger into your reportErrors function to make sure we get there.and  then make sure $scope.state object exists at the moment you try to assign $scope.state['save-mappings']='update';

Comment: is call made using `$http`/ `q$`/`$resource`?

Comment: @PankajParkar:  $http is used.

Comment: @balteo it should work then as hansmaad shown,,

Comment: Thanks all. I actually tried to reproduce a bug I have on a large project. To no avail. Bear with me whilst I try and provide a sample that reproduces the bug..

Comment: It would probably help if you included the sources of `myMethod()` and `postProcess` just in case you've done something wrong somewhere. Also put a `$log.debug()` call in `reportErrors` and `postProcess` to make sure the code you think is executing really is.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan: will do.

Comment: In your `.then` your calling other services which i assume are returning promises. Do any of them define a `.catch` which is catching the error? If they are but arn't returning a rejected promise then any catches further down the chain won't be thrown. The error will be swallowed and the cain after the service call will continue like nothing happened. Just an idea but heres a fiddle with a quick demo of what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/1eLogd9t/

Comment: Thanks @ste2425 the error is not swallowed and the reportError callback does get called...